# Does meteor minify the files in the client/compatibility directory in production?

Tags: javascript, meteor, minify

From this link (http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp) the `client/compatibility` directory is the place to directly put client files that aren't smart packages in Meteor.

However, does Meteor still minify the files in this directory in production? i.e., should I put pre-minified or just non-minified libraries in that directory for my application?

Comment: In the Meteorite packages I've built, I just put the already-minified JavaScript and CSS files and Meteor is happy both in dev and prod. But I haven't looked to see if the files are any different after packaging for prod, since they seem to work okay. Anyway, I suspect the primary reason you might choose to use not-yet-minified files was if you are actively editing them or using them for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This place (though unofficial) is better for Meteor-structure IMHO: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files

I'm afraid I've never tried the compatibility folder in a deployed app so I really don't know.